# Make Checkbox Required JS/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I have a form where I have a consent checkbox (due to LGPD) and I need to make it required before submit.

I already tried a bunch of things but I can`t make it work properly.
Can you guys help me do it?

The idea is simple: make the checkbox required before submitting the form. If its not checked, an error message needs to show up.

```
    function(require,module,exports){
  var CheckBoxCustom,
    bind = function(fn, me){ return function(){ return fn.apply(me, arguments); }; };

  CheckBoxCustom = (function() {
    function CheckBoxCustom(config) {
      this._handlerCheckbox = bind(this._handlerCheckbox, this);
      this._options = {
        text: config.text,
        container: config.container,
        "class": config["class"],
        checked: config.checked,
        required: true,
        message: 'É necessário concordar com nossos termos de uso.',
      };
      this._externalContainer = this._options.container;
      this._checkBoxContainer = void 0;
      this._create();
    }

    CheckBoxCustom.prototype._create = function() {
      this._checkBoxContainer = $('<div/>').addClass(this._options["class"]);
      this._externalContainer.append(this._checkBoxContainer);
      this._span = $('<span/>');
      this._i = $('<i/>');
      this._checkBox = $('<a/>').text(this._options.text).attr({
      });
      this._span.append(this._i);
      this._checkBox.append(this._span);
      this._checkBoxContainer.append(this._checkBox);
      this._checkBox.on('click', this._handlerCheckbox);
      if (this._options.checked === true) {
        return this._checkBoxContainer.addClass('checked');
      }
    };

    CheckBoxCustom.prototype._handlerCheckbox = function(e) {
      return this._checkBoxContainer.toggleClass('checked');
    };

    return CheckBoxCustom;

  })();

  module.exports = CheckBoxCustom;

     this._checkBox = new CheckBoxCustom({
        name: 'termos',
        text: 'Li e concordo com o tratamento dos meus dados pessoais conforme previsto na Declaração de Privacidade para Website Audi.',
        container: this._formGroupNews,
        "class": 'newsletterCheckbox',
        "data-parsley-required": "true",
        checked: false,
        required: true,
        message: 'Custom error message here',
        required: function(elem)
            {
                return $("input.select:checked").length > 0;
            }
      });
```

Comment: This is a monstrous amount of code for one checkbox! in your `this._checkBox = new CheckBoxCustom` fn you have `required` key twice.

Comment: But the validation happens on submit or pageUnload or somewhere.. where does the validation occur?

Comment: @Kinglish I removed the duplicated key but nothing works yet. I didnt find any validation for this field, so this may be the problem here. It doesn`t validate, so it wont work. do you know how can I create a validation function?

Also, all required fields have this attr ( "data-parsley-required": "true", )

Comment: It would be easier if I understood the context. At which point do you need to validate this? On form submit? what is the action the user will take which will trigger the need to check this required variable?

Comment: @Kinglish on form submit. this checkbox is the last item of the form. Its a LGPD consent box with the terms of use. So the user must check this checkbox in order to submit the entire form. If its not checked, submit should return a message like it does on all other required fields.